# Sqlplus doesnt print entire select output, while SQLdeveloper does

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

when i execute a query on SQLdeveloper

```
select text from dba_views where VIEW_NAME='EG_Name' and owner='user123';
```

I get the result

```
select
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       col5  from Table1
```

but when i execute the same query on sqlplus i get a truncated output like

```
TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       c
SQL>
```

for some reason it is being truncated?

Anyone have an idea.

Answer (score 3):

`dba_views.text` is data type `long`. You need to increase the default display size [from the default 80 characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699121):

```
set long 32767
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Stackoverflow is awesome!. You fixed this issue in 5 mins, which our team was trying to fix since 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query after setting the sqlplus session :

```
set pagesize 100;
set linesize 10000;
set num 20;
```

You can refer docs at the following link for more information:
[`http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1011230`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1011230)